# pgAdmin4 how can I see where this function is used

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

i use pgAdmin4 for PostgreSQL database.
There is a database with a large number of procedures and functions. I want to change one of the functions, how can I see where this function is used?

[image]

Comment: could you provide more context?

Comment: Where do you manage your source code?

Comment: i use pgAdmin4 for PostgreSQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot find that information with pgAdmin4, and you cannot find it in PostgreSQL at all.

First, the procedure could be called from client code, and that is not inside the database.

But it is also not easy to determine the procedure calls from other functions and procedures inside the database. Function and procedure bodies are stored as strings, and PostgreSQL cannot track dependencies. You could try a query like

```
SELECT oid::regprocedure
FROM pg_proc
WHERE prosrc ~* 'call\s+myproc`;
```

But that would also match `CALL myproc_not_really(42);` and would miss `EXECUTE format('CALL %s(42)', 'myproc()'::regprocedure);`.

Comment: I agree with you, it is difficult to track function calls on the client. But it would be possible to find calls in internal functions and procedure. It is a pity that this functionality has not been implemented yet. It looks like I'll have to do a text search in the backup file myself.

Comment: That functionality will probably never be implemented.